# Links & Tags send to empty page when clicked on

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink, tumblr, broken-links

I'm re-writing my tumblr theme but when certain links and tags are cicked on I am directed to an empty page with only the search box on it. (http://this-ones-for-the-freaks.tumblr.com/post/115865391718/dylanfuller-this-scene-fucked-me-up-because-he)

It doesn't happen for all links though - the one to my archive works fine as does searching certain things in the box or clicking the tags (i.e I can search 'Hayley Atwell' and it will work fine. When I click on the information on a post to show notes it sends me to the same blank page. 
Where is the issue in the code that's causing this and how might I fix it! - It was working fine yesterday so I think I must have deleted something or interrupted a line maybe?

My blog code looks like:

---

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>{Title}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
    {block:Description}
    <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
    {/block:Description}


    <head>



         <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Lato:100,300,400,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- VARIABLES -->

    <meta name="image:Background" content="http://static.tumblr.com/vqqnpua/Nvlmbhjyn/straws.png"/>
    <meta name="image:Sidebar Image 2" content="" />

    <meta name="color:Background" content="#fdf3ee" />
    <meta name="color:Text" content="#797979" />
    <meta name="color:Bold" content="#ff4a00" />
    <meta name="color:Italic" content="#ff4a00" />
    <meta name="color:Link" content="#a09280" />
    <meta name="color:Content BG" content="#ffffff" />
    <meta name="color:Content Border" content="#ebebeb" />
    <meta name="color:Info BG" content="#f3f3f3" />
    <meta name="color:Info Border" content="#e4e2e1" />
    <meta name="color:visited" content="#e4e2e1" />


    <meta name="text:Link 1 URL" content="http://"/>
    <meta name="text:Link 1" content="Lint 1" />
    <meta name="text:Link 2 URL" content="http://"/>
    <meta name="text:Link 2" content="Link 2" />
    <meta name="text:Link 3 URL" content="http://" />
    <meta name="text:Link 3" content="Link 3" />
    <meta name="text:Link 4 URL" content="http://" />
    <meta name="text:Link 4" content="Link 4" />
    <meta name="text:Link 5 URL" content="http://" />
    <meta name="text:Link 5" content="Link 5" />
    <meta name="text:Link 6 URL" content="http://" />
    <meta name="text:Link 6" content="Link 6" />



    <style type="text/css">



    ::-webkit-scrollbar{
    height: 3px;
    width: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    background-color:#eee;
    }


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color:#c6c6ce;
    }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background-color:#fff;
    }



    /* MAIN */

    body {
        background-color:{color:Background};
        background-image: url('{image:Background}');
        color:{color:Text};
       font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 8px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 9px;

    }

    a:link, a:active {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: {color:Link}; }

     a:visited {
        text-decoration:line-through;
        color: {color:visited}; }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: {color:Bold};}

    b, strong, .strong {color:{color:Bold};}

    blockquote {
        border-left:2px solid {color:Text};
        padding-left:6px; }

    #tumblr_controls{ position:fixed!important; right: 0px; top:0px;}

    i, em, .em {color:{color:Italic};}


    /* CONTENT */


    .contentwhole {
        width:520px;
        z-index:0;
        margin-left:500px;
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }

    .content {
        width:500px;
        z-index:0;
        height: auto;
        padding:16px;
        margin-top:60px;
        background-color: {color:Content BG};
        border:0.5px solid {color:Content Border};
        overflow:auto;
    }

     .thisonesforthefreaks {
         font-family:Abel;
         font-size:7px;
         letter-spacing:3px;
         color:#82828e;
         position:fixed;
         top:305px;
         left:311px;
     }
    .info {
        height:auto;
        float:center;
        padding-top:4px;
        margin-bottom:-10px;
        margin-top:10px;
        opacity:0.5;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:7px;
        font-family:arial;
        letter-spacing:4px;
        background-color: {color:Info BG};
        background-image:url('{image:Info BG}');
        color:{color:Link};
        border-top: 1.6px solid {color:Info Border};
        width: 500px; 

        text-transform:uppercase;
        transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -o-transition-duration: 0.6s; }

    .info a {
        font-size:7px; }

    .info:hover {
        opacity:1.0;
        transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -o-transition-duration: 0.6s; }

    .pagination {
        top:540px;
        left:336px;
        width:100px;
        font-size:20px;
        letter-spacing:12px;
        color:#bbb;
        background:#fff;
        position:fixed;
        font-family:Abel|Lato;
        text-align:center;}

          /* TAGS */

    .tags {
        opacity:0.3; }



    /* SIDEBAR */

    .hover {
        width:100px;
        height:50px;
        top:300px;
        position:fixed;
        left:280px;}

    .sidebar {
        position:fixed;
        top:50px;
        z-index:1000;
        left:30px;
        width:200px;
        height:300px;
    }



    .sidebarcontent {
        width:100px;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px 20px 60px 20px;
        top:300px;
        left:280px;
        height:120px;
        position:absolute;
       border:1px solid #bbb;
        opacity:0.7;
        z-index:3000;
        font-size:17px;
        color:#bbb;
        background:#fff;
        }



    .hover:hover .sidebarcontent {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;}


    .sidebarimage2 {
        opacity:1.0;
        width:88px;
        height:relative;
        margin-top:12px;
        border:1px solid {color:Content Border};


    .sideborder {
        width:1px;
        background-color:{color:Main Links};
        border-right:10px solid {color:Signature Color};
        opacity:0.4;
        margin:0;
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        height:100%;
        left:1000px; }

    /* TAGS */




    /* NAVIGATION */

    #navigation a {
        background-color:#fff
        display:block;
        padding:0px;
        width:2px;

        letter-spacing:0px;
        text-align:left;
        font-family:ariel;
        text-shadow:none;
        text-transform:none;
        color: {color:Bold}; 
        font-family:Abel|Lato;
        font-size:18px;}

    #navigation a:hover {
        background-color: {color:Text};
        color: {color:Background};
        text-shadow:none;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:center;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s linear;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-out;}


    /* EXTRAS */

    .extras {
        width:520px;
        z-index:2000;
        padding:3px;
        letter-spacing:8px;}

    .push {
        background:transparent;
        opacity:0;
        margin-top:0px;
        text-align:left;  
        margin-left:520px;
        position:absolute;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s linear;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-out;}

    .extras:hover .push {
        opacity:1.0;
        margin-left:540px;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s linear;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-out;}


    </style>

<form action="/search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="TYPE TEXT AND ENTER" style="width:142px; height:22px; background-color:#fff; color: #6d5b6d; font-family: 'Lato', cursive; letter-spacing:3.25px;font-size: 7px; border: 1px solid #dadada;position:fixed; top:320px; left:310px"/>

    <div class="pagination">
    {block:Pagination}{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}" <a href="#?w=300" rel="box1" class="poplight">&#8701;        </a></a>{/block:PreviousPage}{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}" <a href="#?w=300" rel="box1" class="poplight">         &#8702;</a></a>{/block:NextPage}{/block:Pagination2}    
    </div>


    <div class="hover">

    <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebarcontent">

    <div id="navigation">
    <div align="centre"><table width="125px" style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;margin-left:-32px;text-align:left;"><td><td width="30%" vAlign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;"><td><td width="30%" vAlign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <a href="{text:Link 1 URL}"title="Home"{text:Link 1}</a>
    <a href="{text:Link 2 URL}"title="Writing"{text:Link 2}</a
    </td>

    <td width="30%" vAlign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <a href="{text:Link 3 URL}"title="About"{text:Link 3}</a>
    <a href="{text:Link 4 URL}"title="Face"<a>{text:Link 4}</a>
    </td>
    <td width="30%" vAlign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <a href="{text:Link 5 URL}"title="Ask"{text:Link 5}</a>
    <a href="{text:Link 6 URL}"title="Archive"<a>{text:Link 6}</a>
    </td> 

    </tr></table></div></div>


    <img src="{image:Sidebar Image 2}" class="sidebarimage2" /><p>

    </div>


    </div>
    </div> <!-- END SIDE IMAGE BORDER -->


    </div> <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
    </div> <!-- END HOVER -->



    <div class="contentwhole">

    {block:Posts}


 <div class="extras">

<div class="push">
<div id="extraslinks">


</div> <!-- END EXTRA LINKS -->


</div> <!-- END EXTRA LINKS -->

<div class="tags">


</div> <!-- END TAGS -->
</div> <!-- END PUSH -->


    <div class="content">


    {block:Text}
    {block:Title}
    <a href="{Permalink}" class="ttitle">{Title}</a>
    {/block:Title}
    {Body}
    {/block:Text}

    {block:Photo}
    <img class="photo" src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Photo}

    {block:Photoset}
    {Photoset-500}
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Photoset}

    {block:Quote}
    {Quote}<p>
    {block:Source}- {Source}{/block:Source}
    {/block:Quote}

    {block:Link}
    <a href="{URL}" target="{Target}" class="ttitle"> {Name} (x) </a>
    {block:Description} {Description} {/block:Description}
    {/block:Link}

    {block:Chat}
    {block:Title} {Title} {/block:Title}
    {block:Lines}{block:Label}<b>{Label}</b>{/block:Label} {Line}<br>

    {/block:Lines}
    {/block:Chat}


    {block:Audio}
    {block:AudioPlayer}{AudioPlayerWhite}{/block:AudioPlayer}
    <p>
    {block:AlbumArt}
    <img src="{AlbumArtURL}" width="100px" />
    {/block:AlbumArt}
    <p>
    {block:Caption}
    {Caption}
    {/block:Caption}
    {/block:Audio}


    {block:Video}
    {Video-500}
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Video}

    {block:Answer}
    {Asker} asked: {Question}<p>
    {Answer}
    {/block:Answer}


    <div class="info">
    {block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">posted {TimeAgo}</a>{/block:Date}
{block:NoteCount}with {NoteCountWithLabel} {/block:NoteCount} <p><div class="tags">

{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}
<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a> 
{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}</p>
    </div> <!--END INFO -->

    {block:PermalinkPage}
    {block:ContentSource} Source: <a href="{SourceURL}" target="_blank">{SourceTitle}</a>{/block:ContentSource}<p>
    {block:PostNotes}
{PostNotes} 
    {/block:PostNotes}
    {/block:PermalinkPage}
    </div> <!-- END CONTENT -->
    </div> <!-- END EXTRAS -->
    {/block:Posts}

    <div class= ""><footer style=height:50px;> </div> <!-- footer -->

    </div> <!-- END CONTENT WHOLE -->
```

Where is the issue?! Thanks!

Comment: `{block:Pagination}{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}" <a href="#?w=300" rel="box1" class="poplight">&#8701;        </a></a>{/block:PreviousPage}{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}" <a href="#?w=300" rel="box1" class="poplight">         &#8702;</a></a>{/block:NextPage}{/block:Pagination2}` - I don't know where to start :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just one typo:

```
 {block:Pagination} ... {/block:Pagination2}
```

Delete the character **2**.

```
 {block:Pagination} ... {/block:Pagination}
```

I've checked on a tumblr blog, now it works.